# Why does the size of Ubuntu 12.04 ISO increase once fully downloaded?

Tags: 12.04, iso

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 three times (32-bit) and on all occasions the 'download' under 'tool' gives the size as 695 MB during the process of downloading. But when it is completed, and seen in the 'Downloads' folder, the size is shown as 729 MB or more. Is it a problem of malware?

I am already using Ubuntu 12.04 (upgraded). I tried to download 12.04.1 for burning in CD and for use by others. I followed the `md5sum ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso` as suggested. It returned `e235b63c02644e219b7bf3668f479c9e` instead of `d791352694374f1c478779f7f4447a3f`.

Answer (score 6):

Probably just a difference in how the size is calculated, you can check the hashes against [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

Since the md5sum of ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso is `d791352694374f1c478779f7f4447a3f`

Running

```
md5sum ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
```

should return that if it downloaded properly.

If you're on Windows, you can follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows).

Edit:
Being as it's most likely due to a faulty download (probably relativity minor, but likely to cause problems with an install) you could try downloading using the [torrent link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) from the [alternative download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads).

BitTorrent should make sure that the resulting file downloaded matches the hash due to the nature of how it works.

Comment: I think you're right, 695*1024*1024/1000 = 728760